# call total from cartactivity to foodlistactivity

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I call the **string totals** from `getOrderItemData()`, which is in `CartActivity` into the `FoodListActivity`.

I want to call the totals and put it into the `str_amount` which is located in the `FoodListActivity`'s `placeOrder()`.

`CartActivity` is the activity called from `FoodListActivity`, which sets the cart. When you click the place order button, it will print the selected food item with the total amount that is calculated in the `CartActivity`.

**CartActivity**

```
   public void getOrderItemData() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null )
    {
        String orderItems = extras.getString("orderItems",null);
        if(orderItems!=null && orderItems.length()>0)
        {
            try{
                JSONArray jsonOrderItems = new JSONArray(orderItems);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonOrderItems.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonOrderItems.getString(i));
                    Food food = new Food(
                            jsonObject.getString("FoodName"),
                            jsonObject.getDouble("FoodPrice")
                   );
                  food.cartQuantity = jsonObject.getInt("CartQuantity");
                    /* Calculate Total*/

                    Total =Total + (food.cartQuantity* food.foodprice);
                    totals=String.valueOf(Total);
                    Orders.add(food);

                }

                if(Orders.size() > 0)
                {
                  CustomAdapter listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,Orders);
                    lvSummary.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                     tvTotal.setText("Order Total:RM "+ totals);
                }
                else
                {
                    showMessage("Empty");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                showMessage(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**FoodListActivity**

```
 public void placeOrder()
{
    Orders.clear();
    lOrderItems.clear();
   for(int i=0;i<listAdapter.strilists.size();i++)
    {
        if(listAdapter.strilists.get(i).cartQuantity > 0)
       {
           Food foods = new Food(
                   listAdapter.strilists.get(i).foodname,
                   listAdapter.strilists.get(i).foodprice
                         );
                        foods.cartQuantity = listAdapter.strilists.get(i).cartQuantity;
                       Orders.add(foods);
           lOrderItems.add(foods.getJsonObject().toString());

                        }

        }
        User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUser();
        String str_id=String.valueOf(user.getId());
        String str_pickuptime=String.valueOf(String.valueOf(ettime.getText()));
        String str_pickupdate=String.valueOf(date);

        String str_amount=String.valueOf();
        String type="order";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker=new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type,str_id,str_pickuptime,str_pickupdate,str_amount);
       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(lOrderItems);
         openSummary(jsonArray.toString());

       }
```

Comment: try saving it into SharedPreference. then you will not need to worry about the state of either Activities. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static variable so you can call it from another Activity.

Example:

**FoodListActivity** - define as:

```
public class FoodListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static double cartTotal;
    ...
}
```

**CartActivity** - call it from anywhere:

```
double cartTotal = FoodListActivity.cartTotal;
```

As long as you don't kill 'FoodListActivity', your variable `cartTotal` can be accessed.

Comment: After I add the static, I can get the total. But I now have one problem where it will only insert the previous data into the table after the second time of place order is press and the current pressed data is not insert and need to wait next order press.

Answer (score 0):

> First way:-

you can **take total variable as public static variable in Base activity or any place from which you want to get data then you can use total variable publicly** in your cart activity.

For example so below,

```
public class FoodListActivity extends Activity {

    public static yourdatatype total; //datatype - like int,double or float what you require

}

public class CartActivity extends Activity {

    yourdatatype total = FoodListActivity.total;

}

//you can also use this variable in any other activity also.
```

> Second way:-

**You can also create a baseActivity as a base of all activity. It is good for more complex and large number of code.**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompactActivity {

        public static yourdatatype total; //datatype - like int,double or float

    }
```

And you can use total variable directly in any activity like if you want to get total in cart activity then just extends your baseActivity to cart activity.

like:-

```
public class CartActivity extends BaseActivity {

        yourdatatype gettotal = total//datatype - total get from base activity.

    }
```